# If $P(X_i > x) = e^{-x}$, how to prove $\max_{1\le m\le n}X_m/\log n \to 1 a.s$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Here is a question from Rick Durrett's Probability. Exercise 2.3.18.

$X_1,X_2,...$ are i.i.d. with $P(X_i > x) = e^{-x}$, $M_n = \max_{1\le m\le n} X_m$. Prove that $M_n/\log n \to 1$ a.s.

My solution:

Clearly, we can show by Borel-Cantelli lemma that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} X_n/\log n = 1$ a.s.. By this it is easy to prove that $P(M_n \le (1+\varepsilon)\log n) < \infty$ and hence $\limsup_{n\to\infty} M_n / \log n \le 1$. On the other hand, we need to show that $P(M_n \le (1-\varepsilon)\log n) = 0$ as $n\to \infty$. However, I could only prove that $P(M_n \le (1-\varepsilon)\log n) = 1 - n^{-(1-\varepsilon)}$ and when $n\to\infty$ this probability goes to $1$. It is strange, because that means $M_n \le \log n$ when $n\to\infty$ and this contradicts the question.

I see the answer wrote by Durrett says:$P(M_n < (1-\varepsilon )\log n) = (1 - n^{-(1-\varepsilon)})^n \le e^{-n^\varepsilon}$, and it is summable, by B-C lemma shows $P(M_n < (1-\varepsilon )\log n ,i.o.) = 0$.

However, why is $P(X_i < (1-\varepsilon )\log n) = (1 - n^{-(1-\varepsilon)})^n$?

$P(X_i\le x) = 1 - e^{-x}$, thus $P(X_i \le(1-\varepsilon)\log n) = 1- e^{\log (n^{-(1-\varepsilon)})} = 1 - n^{-(1-\varepsilon)}$ and there is no such $(\cdot)^n$.

Is there anything wrong in my proof? Or the question itself is wrong?

Comment: The Durrett answer should actually say $P[M_n<(1-\epsilon)\log(n)] = (1-n^{-(1-\epsilon)})^n$. This follows from computing the CDF of a max of iid random variables, which can be done from first principles.

Comment: Yes, I corrected my post just now. But how to compute it? Please leave an answer and I will appreciate it very much!

Comment: I have understood the proof, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $M_n = \max_{1\le m\le n} X_m$ thus,

$P(M_n < (1-\varepsilon)\log n) = P(\max_{1\le m\le n} X_m < (1-\varepsilon)\log n) = P(X_1 < (1-\varepsilon)\log n,\cdots,X_n < (1-\varepsilon)\log n) = \prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i< (1-\varepsilon)\log n) = (1-n^{-(1-\varepsilon)})^n.$

The last equation comes from  $X_n$ are i.i.d.

We have the inequality: $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-\frac{k}{n})^n\le e^{-k}$, thus $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1-\frac{1}{n^{1-\varepsilon}})^n = \lim_{n\to\infty} (1-\frac{n^\varepsilon}{n})^n \le  e^{-n^\varepsilon}$, and this gives the result.

Comment: The equation $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1-\frac{1}{n})^n=e^{-n}$  does not make sense, since the left-hand-side does not depend on $n$, while the right-hand-side does.

Comment: I made a mistake, thanks for pointing out! The corrected answer has been updated.

Comment: Again the limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1-\frac{n^{\epsilon}}{n})^n = e^{-n^{\epsilon}}$ does not make sense, since the left-hand-side does not depend on $n$, while the right-hand-side does.  Anyway, I do not know why you are taking that limit (why is that limit useful? Borel-Cantelli talks about sums, not limits). The approach of Durrett seems use the inequality $(1-\frac{x}{n})^n\leq e^{-x}$ for $0\leq x\leq n$.  A plot of $(1-1/n)^n$ as a function of $n$ is here: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+%281-1%2Fn%29%5En%2C+n%3D1..10

Comment: Durrett's answer wrote that : $P(M_n<(1−\varepsilon)\log n)=(1−n^{−(1−\varepsilon)})^n\le e^{−n^ε}$. In order to use Borel-Cantelli lemma, we need $P(M_n<(1−\varepsilon)\log n)$ to be summable. And $\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-n^\varepsilon}$ is summable, by the comparative convergence principle of series, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(M_n<(1−\varepsilon)\log n)$ is convergent.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't write $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1 - \frac{n^\varepsilon}{n})^n = e^{-n^\varepsilon}$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty} (1 - \frac{n^\varepsilon}{n})^n \le e^{-n^\varepsilon}$ more correctly?

Comment: The point is that Durrett’s answer uses a sum, not a limit. I do not know why you are introducing a limit. The following limit is true (assuming $0<\epsilon<1$) but is not useful for this problem: $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (1-n^{\epsilon}/n)^n=0$$

Comment: You are right. There is no need of the limit. I was thinking of how to come up with the $n^\varepsilon$ and didn't think about the inequality. I am much more clear about the proof. Thanks for the discussion!